# Bootstrap 4.1 form validations classes not working in angular 7

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7

My form validation error messages not showing in red color and not highlighted input field too,it's showing in black color.But I used these classes in bootstrap version 3,then it was working properly.

here is the code I'm trying

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': (email.touched || email.dirty) && !email.valid}">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email"
                  required pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" #email="ngModel">
                  <div *ngIf="(email.touched || email.dirty) && email.errors" class="help-block">
                      <span *ngIf="email.errors.required"  >Email required</span>
                      <span *ngIf="email.errors.pattern" >Invalid email</span>
                    </div>
                   </div>
```

I tried 4.1 classes,but I couldn't understand them. 
Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

in order to show the input field in form with red border to show that is not valid, you can use simply one css class. first in your css chapter in your component add this class:

```
.form-control.ng-touched.ng-invalid{border:2px solid red;}
```

this class automatically check the validation of the input filed and you can delete the ngClass. 
now for checking the validation and displaying the error message you should like this:

```
  <div *ngIf= "email.touched && email.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                  <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email required</div>
                  <div *ngIf="email.errors.pattern" >Invalid email</div>
  </div>
```